# Comparing two large files are taking over four hours

Tags: php, c++, server, shopify

I have an online store that has about 15,000 products that get's updated everyday. Currently I upload the new list everyday, but it poses some issues (like downtime being a huge issue) and I wanted to come up with an alternative. 
I created a script that moves the "yesterdays" products list and downloads today's products list. Then I go line-by-line and compare the two files seeing what needs to be deleted, modified, are created. This will allow me to perform an update with minimal amount of work, no downtime since everything will happen behind the scenes via CRON job, and it's how it should done.

The problem I have is it takes over four hours for the process to happen and I'm not sure if what I'm doing is the most efficient way. My first thought is to write something in C++, but I'm not sure how much faster that would be compared to PHP.

My question(s) is:

•  Is this the most efficient way to do this?

•  Is PHP the best language to do this?

Here's my script I wrote that handles the download and comparison:

```
public function __construct($url, $user, $pass)
{
    $this->logger = new KLogger("/opt/lampp/htdocs/lea/logs/master.log" , KLogger::INFO);

    /* increase execution time and server memory limit */
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 14400);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

    /* set veriables */
    $this->ftp   = ftp_connect($url);
    $this->login = ftp_login($this->ftp, $user, $pass);

    $this->old = file('/opt/lampp/htdocs/lea/products/new/temp/rsr_inventory.txt');
    $this->new = file('/opt/lampp/htdocs/lea/products/new/rsr_inventory.txt');

    $this->list = array();

    $this->start_time = date('Hi');

    $this->counter = 0;
}

public function download($to, $from)
{
    // move current file to new location to get new file ready
    $this->logger->LogInfo('move yesterday\'s products list');
    rename('/opt/lampp/htdocs/lea/products/new/temp/rsr_inventory.txt', '/opt/lampp/htdocs/lea/products/new/rsr_inventory.txt');                

    // get list from rsr    
    $this->logger->LogInfo('get new list from rsr');        
    if(ftp_get($this->ftp, $to, $from, FTP_BINARY))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function update()
{
    // initialize process
    $this->logger->LogInfo('update process initialized');

    for($i = 0; $i < count($this->new); $i++)
    {
        $new[$i] = explode(';', $this->new[$i]);
        $response = $this->_match($new[$i]);
        if($response[0])
        {
            if(trim($response[2]) != trim($new[$i][5]) || trim($response[3]) != trim($new[$i][8]))
            {
                $this->list[$this->counter][0] = $response[1];
                $this->list[$this->counter][1] = 'update';
                $this->list[$this->counter][2] = trim($response[2]);
                $this->list[$this->counter][3] = trim($response[3]);
                $this->counter++;
            }                               
        }
        else
        {
            $this->list[$this->counter][0] = $response[1];
            $this->list[$this->counter][1] = 'create';
            $this->list[$this->counter][2] = trim($response[2]);
            $this->list[$this->counter][3] = trim($response[3]);
            $this->counter++;
        }           
    }
    if(count($this->list) > 0)
    {
        //csv           
        $this->logger->LogInfo('create update.csv');

        $updates = fopen('/opt/lampp/htdocs/lea/products/new/updates.csv', 'w');
        foreach($this->list as $fields)
        {
            fputcsv($updates, $fields);
        }
        fclose($updates);
    }

    $this->logger->LogInfo('product update process complete');
    $this->__mail();

}

private function _match($item)
{       
    for($j = 0; $j < count($this->old); $j++)
    {
        $old[$j] = explode(';', $this->old[$j]);

        if($item[0] === $old[$j][0])
        {                               
            return array(true, $item[0], $old[$j][5], $old[$j][8]);
        }
    }       
    return array(false, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Here is an example of the products.txt file I get everyday (I'm only showing 10 products, but there are roughly 15,000 (there is a lot of things missing; prices, qty, and etc..., but I shortened everything up since it doesn't matter to show those) :

```
511-10010-019-L-XL;844802282208;5.11 RECON ANKLE SOCK BLK L/XL; 
511-10010-036-L-XL;844802282246;5.11 RECON ANKLE SOCK SHADOW L/XL; 
511-10010-132-LXL;844802334662;5.11 RECON ANKLE SOCK TIMBER L/XL;
511-10010-200-L-XL;844802282222;5.11 RECON ANKLE SOCK FATIGUE L/XL; 
511-10011-019-L-XL;844802276382;5.11 COLD WEATHER OTC SOCK BLK L/XL; 
511-10012-019-L-XL;844802276429;5.11 COLD WEATHER CREW SOCK BLK L/XL; 
511-30012-019-M;844802269650;5.11 WOMENS HOLSTER SHIRT BLK M; 
511-40011-010-L;844802016148;5.11 HOLSTER SHIRT L WHITE; 
511-40011-010-M;844802016131;5.11 HOLSTER SHIRT M WHITE; 
511-40011-010-XL;844802016155;5.11 HOLSTER SHIRT XL WHITE; 
511-40011-010-XXL;844802016162;5.11 HOLSTER SHIRT 2XL WHITE;
```

Comment: screams - use a database

Comment: What size is the actual file?

Comment: what about using the linux `diff` command to find modified areas (assuming this runs on a linux server)?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, using a database, wouldn't I have to still parse the new text file everyday and compare each line to a record in the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are doing 15000 x 15000 comparisons (so 225 million operations on the data).

If you instead create a map (in other words an array in PHP) with some unique identifier as the index for both the old and the new. That is 30k operations, and then iterate over the one list checking if the other contains the same thing or not. That's another 15K operations. Total of 45K operations, rather than 225M operations.

I'm not saying the suggestion to do a database is a bad idea, but the excessive time it takes is clearly caused by a poor choice of algorithm +  data structure.

Comment: Mats - I'll try this approach and see how it works out. After thinking about it, it seems like a good approach.

Comment: Holy crap! Using this approach, it took the whole process about 5 MINUTES. HUUUGE savings...and that is not an exaggeration. Thanks for taking the time to provide your feedback.

Comment: I would also like to point out that I was exploding the file on every iteration which is VERY costly. Putting each file into an array when the Products object is instantiated was a huge time saver and correct way to handle the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for MySQL. Importing your data will be a substantial investment up front, but will be worth it in the long run. Databases are designed to update, merge, delete, and insert data efficiently. This sort of job would take seconds in MySQL. You could keep PHP as your scripting language.

Comment: Are you saying that you can just import the CSV file and have MySQL automagically figure out what changed? I would have thought you still need to know what has changed?

Comment: You would have to write some SQL to do the comparison. Import the CSV to a new table and then use SQL to compare and modify.

Comment: Yes. A little PHP script can be written to import the data he receives daily into its own table, then with a few simple queries it can be quickly compared to existing data to make the necessary updates.

Comment: cantalope - I'm going to try you approach and mats to see what yields the best times. I really appreciate the direction and feedback.